# cambiar el orden de los valores que aparecen en el select dinamico - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Tengo un select dinamico que se crea a partir del valor que se agrega en un input, por ejemplo si en el input agrego el valor de 4 entonces se me genera un select con los numeros del 1 al 4 y si selecciono por ejemplo en el select el valor del 1 se me carga otro select dinámico con el resto de números del 2 al 4 y así hasta quedar solo el valor del 4.
**Ahora lo que necesito es que haga lo contrario si agrego en el input el valor del 4 entonces en el select me va a cargar los valores del 4 al 1 y si selecciono el numero 4 entonces me cargue en otro select los números del 3 hasta 1 y así consecutivamente hasta solo quedar el valor del 1.**

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-dawn-c55ux?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estás sobre complicándote, si solo necesitas un `select` con el número de elementos especificado por un número máximo, entonces la única información relevante (que define el estado de tu elemento) son simplemente el tamaño y el orden, simplifiqué el código para proveer una solución tal y como la describes:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Test = () => {

  //Necesitamos conocer el tamaño del array
  const [size, setSize] = useState(0);
  //Necesitamos conocer si el array es ascendente o descendente
  const [reversed, setReversed] = useState(false);

  const buildSelectArray = () => {

    //Creamos un array del tamaño de size y lo llenamos de ceros
    //Utilizamos map para generar un array con las opciones que queremos
    //Es importante utilizar el prop keys para elementos autogenerados
    //De lo contrario tu código podría comportarse de maneras inesperadas
    //Utilzo una función ternaria para poder decidir el orden del array
    return Array(size)
      .fill(0)
      .map((el, index) => (
        <option
          key={`select${reversed ? size - index : index}`}
          value={reversed ? size - index : index + 1}
        >
          {reversed ? size - index : index + 1}
        </option>
      ));
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    //Al especificar el tamaÑo seteamos el estado size de tu componente
    setSize(Number(event.target.numberIni.value));
  };
  const resetForm = () => {
    //Al resetear el tamaño de tu componente hacemos size 0
    setSize(0);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input name="numberIni" type="number" />
        <input type="submit" value="Generar select" />
      </form>
      {
        /* Evaluamos si size es mayor que cero para hacer el display de las opciones */
        size > 0 && (
        <select name="" id="">
          {buildSelectArray()}
        </select>
      )}

      {size > 0 && (
        <input onClick={() => resetForm()} type="button" value="Reiniciar" />
      )}

      <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          /* Si los acomodamos al reves entonces cambiamos el estado que nos ayuda con el orden*/
          setReversed(!reversed);
        }}
      >
        Reverse
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Test;
```

Comment: hola amigo, revise el código que me enviaste pero no hace lo que necesito , lo que necesito es que haga lo contrario ejemplo en el input hay un 4 y se genera en el select en este orden 4, 3, 2, 1 entonces selecciono el numero 3 y debe crearse otro select desde el 2 hasta el 1 y asi hasta llegar al 1